# Discord.py replit Traceback problem, pops up after several refreshes

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

Okay, so you create a bot, Let's say. You do everything, everything in fact. and your bot runs... sweet, but after refreshing several times, you run into a problem, and it says something so random that your code doesnt even contain. It's this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line x, in <module>
```

And writes a huge HTML block of words, that your token is wrong. anybody knows how to solve this issue? It's not codes fault, It's replits fault probably

```
bot.run(token)
  File "/home/runner/programName/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
```

Please, If anybody knows this solution. Please respond to my message, Thank you!

I ran to an error, And I'm trying to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely encountering issues related to rate limiting when you host your bot on replit. That's because replit gives the same IP to all free users so it's being banned from discord. That's why replit is bad for hosting discord bots. There are other free services you can use like Google Cloud, Oracle Cloud, fly.io, deta.sh, etc. I personally use Amazon AWS free year trial and it's quite good.

Comment: Thank you good sir for helping, May I try using vpn to overcome such problem?

Comment: A VPN will only change your PC's IP. not Replit's. Unfortunately, there is no way to change the IP that is being provided to your bot. And even when you don't get banned your bot will die if it's not being used for a while. And there are security issues because you can't make your rep private in the free plan. Replit has its uses but hosting discord bots is clearly not one of them. You have a lot of better options.